# Python Single Choice Questions

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

```
def ask_choice_question(prompt, options):
    func = tkinter.Tk()
    v = tkinter.IntVar()
    v.set(-1)
    if(prompt):
        tkinter.Label(func, text=prompt).pack()
    for i, option in enumerate(options):
        tkinter.Radiobutton(func, text=option, variable=v, value=i).pack(anchor="w")
    tkinter.Button(func, text="Submit", command=func.destroy).pack()
    func.mainloop()
    print(v.get())
    if(v.get()== -1):
        return None
    print(options[v.get()])
    return options[v.get()]
```

By throughly looking through this website I have found something like the example above, and modified it slightly.

However, when calling func.destroy it seems the func doesn't return anything, neither do "print()"-s do anything. What do?

EDIT: Actually, something I might add, that this question is asked inside of another Tkinter window, and it actually outputs what needed when that window is closed.

EDIT2: It also may be useful to say, that the menu I'm getting looks something like this: http://prntscr.com/kg516z

Comment: When I execute the function, select an answer and click on Submit, both the print and return parts works. Are you sure you had selected an answer before clicking on the button? Because if not, the function returns 'None'.

Comment: I am quite sure, yet it actually does return "None" at all times. Also, as stated, the print(v.get()) never actually gets triggered.

Comment: Ok, from your edit I think I know what's the problem: you have two `Tk` instances and your `IntVar` belongs to the wrong one hence the empty result. I suggest you to use a single `Tk` instance and replace `func = tkinter.Tk()` by `func = tkinter.Toplevel()`. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I can't quite use only one Tk instance to be honest. Any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that there are several running `Tk` instances (i.e. several tcl interpreters) and the `IntVar` in the function does not belong to `func` but to the `Tk` instance created first. As a consequence, its value is not modified by the radiobuttons.

I advise you to use only a single `Tk` instance, replacing `func = tkinter.Tk()` by `func = tkinter.Toplevel()` and using `wait_window(func)` (wait until `func` is destroyed) instead of `mainloop()`:

```
import tkinter

def ask_choice_question(prompt, options):
    func = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
    v = tkinter.IntVar(root, -1)
    if(prompt):
        tkinter.Label(func, text=prompt).pack()
    for i, option in enumerate(options):
        tkinter.Radiobutton(func, text=option, variable=v, value=i).pack(anchor="w")
    tkinter.Button(func, text="Submit", command=func.destroy).pack()
    func.wait_window(func)
    print(v.get())
    if(v.get()== -1):
        return None
    print(options[v.get()])
    return options[v.get()]


root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Button(root, text='Question',
               command=lambda: print('returns ', ask_choice_question('Question?', ['Answer %i' % i for i in range(1, 5)]))).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If you really want to keep the multiple `Tk` instances, then you need to specify the master of your `IntVar` and also to replace `mainloop()` by `wait_window(func)` (though I don't know why):

```
import tkinter

def ask_choice_question(prompt, options):
    func = tkinter.Tk()
    v = tkinter.IntVar(func, -1)
    if(prompt):
        tkinter.Label(func, text=prompt).pack()
    for i, option in enumerate(options):
        tkinter.Radiobutton(func, text=option, variable=v, value=i).pack(anchor="w")
    tkinter.Button(func, text="Submit", command=func.destroy).pack()
    func.wait_window(func)
    print(v.get())
    if(v.get()== -1):
        return None
    print(options[v.get()])
    return options[v.get()]

root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Button(root, text='Question',
               command=lambda: print('returns ', ask_choice_question('Question?', ['Answer %i' % i for i in range(1, 5)]))).pack()
root.mainloop()
```